# How to change Polymer's resolved animation?

Tags: polymer

When you set `<body unresolved>` for Polymer, it fades the site in over 200ms when ready. [(Source)](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/styling.html) Is there a way to change anything about that? Decrease the time, change the effect, remove it entirely?

Answer (score 1):

Polymer defines the `unresolved` class as such:

```
.unresolved {
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

It also sets a `transition` [(MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) property on body:

```
body {
    transition: opacity ease-in 0.2s;
}
```

This results in the whole body fading in over 200ms when it removes `unresolved` from `<body>`. To change or prevent this, set the `transition` property yourself anywhere below the Polymer import:

```
<style shim-shadowdom>
    body {
        transition: none;
    }
</style>
```